# Amazon DynamoDb ORM for .net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, orm

Are there any fast, simple, ORM for DynamoDB and .NET Core? I have found PocoDynamo but it's not compatible with .net Core.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dynamo.ORM/ ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is no.
Now the long answer: Notice that OR/Ms are used for relational databases, such as *SQL Server*, *Oracle*, *MySql* and so on; because there is a mapping between the table(s) to your object(s) (I wont say Entity because would be longer)... *DynamoDB* is a **NoSQL databae**. *DynamoDb* as *MongoDB* are made to store documents with no specific formats BUT  *DynamoDB* offers to have a key or a hash key been between others rules and differences with *MongoDB*. So, if you have not any way to specify your "Entity" with a free will format "Documents", then there is no reason to use a OR/M.
Now, if Im not wrong, what you are looking for is a high level framework to deal with *DynamoDb*, if that the case, [try this one](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html) offered by AWS team... just one note... if you want to make crazy scans, as today, you would need the low level api.

Comment: makes sense. thank you

Comment: `Notice that OR/Ms are used for relational databases` this is not true. There are providers for MongoDB, and Microsoft themselves have a provider for CosmosDB. There are still benefits to using an ORM even with no-SQL databases.

Comment: @julealgon true, but it is a bit of a misnomer -- the "R" in "ORM" is for "Relational".  So while there are ORM-adjacent solutions for NoSQL, and perhaps plugins for ORM frameworks to talk to non-relational systems they technically aren't serving the purpose of beign an Object-Relational Mapper.